# BOOST async_receive doesn't return when socket is closed

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to write a simple client/server program using *boost.asio*.
My problem is that when the client closes it's socket and exits, "stream.async_receive()" blocks the server side and doesn't return.

Here's my code:

```
#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

asio::awaitable<void> handle_connection(tcp::socket&& stream)
{
    std::cout << "new connection\n";
    std::string buffer;
    uint64_t buffer_size;

    while(stream.is_open())
    {
        co_await stream.async_receive(asio::buffer(&buffer_size, 8), asio::use_awaitable);
        buffer = std::string(buffer_size, '\0');
        std::cout << "message size: " << buffer_size << "\n";
        co_await stream.async_receive(asio::buffer(buffer, buffer_size), asio::use_awaitable);
        std::cout << "new message: " << buffer << "\n";
    }
    // The program never reached this point.
    cout << "socket closed\n";
    co_return;
}

asio::awaitable<void> accept_connection()
{
    auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ex, {{}, 8000});

    tcp::socket sock = co_await acceptor.async_accept(asio::use_awaitable);
    while(true)
    {
        co_spawn(ex, handle_connection(std::move(sock)), asio::detached);
        sock = co_await acceptor.async_accept(asio::use_awaitable);
    }

    co_return;
}

int main()
{
    asio::io_context io_ctx(2);
    co_spawn(io_ctx, accept_connection(), asio::detached);
    io_ctx.run();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop exits. By exception. Because you you don't handle the exception you don't see it.

To show you three ways in which to handle the errors (including Eof):

```
asio::awaitable<void> handle_connection(tcp::socket stream) {
    std::cout << "new connection" << std::endl;

    for (std::string buffer; true;)
        try {
            boost::endian::big_uint64_t buffer_size[1];
            co_await stream.async_receive(asio::buffer(buffer_size), use_awaitable);
            buffer.assign(*buffer_size, '\0');
            std::cout << "message size: " << *buffer_size << "" << std::endl;
            auto [ec, n] =
                co_await stream.async_receive(asio::buffer(buffer), as_tuple(use_awaitable));

            if (n) {
                buffer.resize(n);
                std::cout << "new message: " << buffer << "" << std::endl;
            }

            if (ec) {
                std::cout << "socket closed (ec: " << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
            std::cout << "socket closed (thrown ec: " << se.code().message() << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cout << "socket closed (exception: " << e.what() << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
}
```

I'd suggest sticking to the `error_code` approach, as it is the only approach (with C++20 coro's) that allows you to gracefully handle partial success (e.g. when the connection is lost half-way receiving the expected bytes).

> *Whether partial success makes sense depends on your application. Note that if handled without caution this (dealing with unintended partial messages) may lead to security issues.*

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd5d2c75fda0cdd6)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using asio::use_awaitable;

asio::awaitable<void> handle_connection(tcp::socket stream) {
    auto tok = as_tuple(use_awaitable);
    std::cout << "new connection" << std::endl;

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    for (std::string buffer;;) {
        boost::endian::big_uint64_t buffer_size[1];
        size_t n = 0;

        tie(ec, std::ignore) = co_await stream.async_receive(asio::buffer(buffer_size), tok);
        if (ec) break;

        std::cout << "message size: " << *buffer_size << std::endl;
        buffer.assign(*buffer_size, '\0');

        std::tie(ec, n) = co_await stream.async_receive(asio::buffer(buffer), tok);

        if (n) {
            buffer.resize(n);
            std::cout << "new message: " << buffer << std::endl;
        }

        if (ec) break;
    }
    std::cout << "socket closed (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
}

asio::awaitable<void> accept_connection() {
    auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(ex, {{}, 8989});

    while (true) {
        co_spawn(
            ex,
            handle_connection(co_await acceptor.async_accept(make_strand(ex), use_awaitable)),
            asio::detached);
    }
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context io_ctx;
    co_spawn(io_ctx, accept_connection(), asio::detached);
    io_ctx.run();
}
```

Testing with

```
g++ -std=c++20 -Os -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp;
./a.out& sleep 1;
printf '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0cHello world!\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03Bye' | nc 127.0.0.1 8000 -w 1
```

Prints

```
new connection
message size: 12
new message: Hello world!
message size: 3
new message: Bye
socket closed (End of file)
```

Interactive:

[image]